# How do you call the technique where you slap the bow against the string?

Tags: notation, technique, double-bass

I'm talking about this kind of technique (at the beginning of the video):

How would I notate this kind of technique on paper?

Comment: I think the technical term for what he does there is “wizardry”...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "ricochet bowing". The video uses cello, but the principle is the same.

The notation is just a text instruction, "ricochet", "jeté", or "staccato volante". The exact difference, if any, between the three techniques can a good topic for endless argument that doesn't lead anywhere very useful!

The notes are often written with staccato dots plus a slur - though as the video says, the choice of up and down bows is more about "what feels comfortable" to an individual player than about what sound is produced.